# SagePay integration from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I’ve been asked to integrate a windows form application with SagePay to take payments directly from the application. The SagePay documentation talks about ASP.NET so I’m not sure whether this is possible. Has anyone integrated a WinForm application with SagePay before? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know some payment processors have a connection option where the payment part is hosted on a form on their server. You could try embedding a web browser control into your app to display the payment page.

Usually there is another type of connection option where you can send your information via HttpWebRequest, but I'm not sure that this would work as it requires SSL. Since you are running your app as a desktop client, I'm not sure what you would have available.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is possible given that sagepay needs to redirect users to Mastercard securecode or Verified by Visa, I think they would need to redirect to the bank which then redirects back to a supplied URL. I would think this needs to be within a browser environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can post to urls and get back a response via .net objects and parse the results to display on a form.

You can also ask SagePay to create a Vendor account with 3d secure switched off. This allows you to take payments in house in your winforms app without the customers password however most card vendors if you bypass 3d secure will not protect you if someone calls and uses a card fraudulently.

However it can definitely be done.

You can normally post to secure servers from non secure pages so again this isn't usually an issue.