# Winforms SagePay integration

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SagePay integration from Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364050/sagepay-integration-from-windows-forms)

With reference to [SagePay integration from Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364050/sagepay-integration-from-windows-forms/14457519#14457519) has anyone managed to intergrate SagePay to a winforms application. If so could you give a few pointers to the approach you took?

Comment: Which SagePay integration method are you trying to use? I would imagine Server Integration would work fine. You will need to whitelist any client IP's in the SagePay terminal though, so your program won't work from any IP.

Comment: Am now using the Server integration seems to be heading in the right direction so thanks for that, but any thoughts on how to handle the NotificationURL as looks like it wants a publicly facing Url.